# c# Unity Sharing Script with different instances

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The problem is I have a class for a potato, and when i use it via inventory, it should take a use off the potato, and only that potato. Instead, its taking it off every potato in the game, is there a way to make it where all the potatos have their own instance of the code?

```
public class Food : Item {
    public float healthHealedOnUse;
    public int uses;
}//name ect is in the Item base class
```

Code I am using for Inventory:

```
    public void UseItem(){
    if (item != null) {
        if (item is Food) {
            Debug.Log ("using "+item.name);
            PHH.Heal (((Food)item).healthHealedOnUse);
            ((Food)item).uses--;
            if(((Food)item).uses < 1){
                ClearSlot();
            }
        } else {
            item.Use ();
        }
```

It is effecting all potatos, not just the one I click on.

Adding to Inventory

```
public List<Item> items = new List<Item>();
public bool add(Item item){
    if (items.Count >= space) {
        Debug.Log ("Inventory Full");
        return false;
    } else {
        items.Add (item);
        onItemChangedCallback.Invoke ();
        return true;
    }
}
```

Player picking up item script

```
void PickUp(){
    Debug.Log ("Picking up " + item.name+"!");
    bool wasPickedUp = Inventory.instance.add (item);
    //Debug.Log(wasPickedUp);
    if (wasPickedUp == true) {
        Destroy (gameObject);
    }
```

Code adding item into a inventory slot

```
public void AddItem(Item newItem){
    item = newItem;
    icon.sprite = item.icon;
    icon.enabled = true;
    removeButton.interactable = true;
}
```

How i am displaying items in inventory slots

```
Inventory inventory;
public GameObject Inventoryui;
public Transform itemsParent;
InventorySlot[] slots;
void Start () {
    Inventoryui.SetActive (false);
    inventory = Inventory.instance;
    inventory.onItemChangedCallback += UpdateUI;
    slots = itemsParent.GetComponentsInChildren<InventorySlot> ();
}

public void ToggleInventory(){

    Inventoryui.SetActive (!Inventoryui.activeSelf);
}
void UpdateUI(){
    Debug.Log ("Updating UI");
    for (int i = 0; i < slots.Length; i++) {
        if (i < inventory.items.Count) {
            slots [i].AddItem (inventory.items [i]);
        } else {
            slots [i].ClearSlot ();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: We need to see more code. How are you adding items to the inventory?

Comment: Also, you should just make your `Food` class's `Use()` method heal the player. That's the point of subclassing: `Item#Use` is marked `virtual` and then `Food#Use` is marked `override` and you can just make `UseItem()` call `item.Use()`, done.

Comment: there you go, i added the additem in there

Comment: Regarding the Food's use class, i thought this would be better then having to find the player component, then get the player stats handler off of player.

Comment: I turned that into an answer on your *other* question. Regarding this...I now need to know where you're calling `add` from: that is, I need to see how you get multiple potatoes into your inventory. Odds are you're doing something like `var POTATO = new Food(); /*...*/ Player.inventory.add(POTATO);` causing all of your inventory items to be references to the same object.

Comment: I have a prefab of lets say the potato, which has a pickup script, which takes it a scriptible item, which is in my case, food, which as you saw is what holds the information of the potato, and if it matters, im using a collider to pick up the item.Also added some more code.

Comment: Upon further investigating, I see while in game, both inventory slots are using the same "item/food" (the scriptible object). So it looks like when i place the prefab potato in the game, they all share the same scriptible object script "food", so when i change the uses left on one, its changing it for all potatos in the game with the potato "food" scriptible object attached to it, which has to be all potatos because i use it to hold their values/name/ect.

Answer (score 1):

> ...which takes it a scriptible item

There's your "every reference is the same" problem.

You need to either:

1. clone the scriptable item when it's picked up and add the clone to the player's inventory
2. treat the scriptable item as a singleton that describes what an item is and create an "ItemStack" class the way Minecraft does (there is only one `Potato` object, but all stacks of potatoes are an instance of `ItemStack` which contains a reference to the idealized potato instance).

Comment: where would I clone the scriptable? within the prefab?

Comment: @BrandonG Anytime between when you instantiate the prefab and when it gets added to the player's inventory. Personally I'd do it as part of the `add` method you've already got.